# My current location "my location" is not getting updated on any browser

Tags: macos, geolocation, google-maps

I have enabled "Location services" on my browsers:

[image: Control Center Location Services]

However `maps.google.com` and https://www.gps-coordinates.net/my-location show me either 15 miles to the southwest or 20 miles to the south-southwest.  Why would this be happening?

Comment: I’m assuming you’re on a Mac and connected to the Internet connected to your cable/fiber/telco internet service?

Comment: Only FindMy shows it's accessed your location recently. Where does that think you are? What are you connecting over, wifi, domestic ethernet, phone mast? How built-up is the area, urban, suburban, rural? Have you, or any wifi you use, changed address in the last month or so?

Comment: @Allan  I'm tethered [to mobile phone] presently /traveling. My mobile device sees my precise location. _Precise_ location. As in within four feet

Comment: Does your phone show the correct *precise* location?

Comment: @WestCoastProjects Please confirm whether the Maps app on your Mac shows the correct current location. **If it does not, then this error is caused because your Mac not having a GPS signal so it can't actually know where it is, and the methods employed (Wi-Fi SSID triangulation) failed. **If it does, then this is an issue with Google Chrome or the webpage providing outdated/incorrect information. Does the correct location appear in Safari?

Comment: Incorrect location was being shown  in both Edge and Chrome. Now it is showing the correct location in both.    It seems there was a temporal problem related to tethering that eventually got cleared up?

Comment: @WestCoastProjects Right - since the Mac has no GPS, it's all triangulation of Wi-Fi network names which could clear up once the database refreshes or more signal is obtained.

Comment: I will be that your browser is  using the geolocation of your carrier’s IP and not your actual location data.  Try going to this site:  https://www.iplocation.net/myip and you should find that your IP location isn’t your exact location.

Comment: @Allan  Not in my case here: it uses the previous location which was 20 miles distant (in an urban area where that's multiple cities apart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ezekiel was on the right track.  Asking for Directions on any of my browsers was/is apparently not sufficient to  "wake up" my Mac to the fact I had been traveling.  After opening the `Maps` app, that apparently spurs the Mac to update my current location.